# how to define style for a group of child elements from parent element's style?

Tags: html, css, styles

How can I define the **style attribute values for a group of child elements** from the **parent element's style**.

I want to achieve the following-

```
<div style="style for the child <span> tags">
 <span>a</span>
 <div>b</div>
 <span>c</span>
 <div>d</div>
</div>
```

Say I want to set the color of the text **only** in the child `<span>` tags but not for the text in  the child `<div>` tags. Here I want to know how to do it in case of both ***inline and internal CSS***.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it inline.

Give your main div an id, let's use `container`. The css would be like this:

```
div#container span {
    styles for the spans inside the main div
}
```

Of course, if you have more than one such container div, use class instead of id. The approach is the same.

Comment: Actually currently I am in need of the implementation for **inline CSS** to do it. and I need this for my blog.

Comment: @RajeshPaul **NOT POSSIBLE**

Comment: @RajeshPaul I said it in the first line of my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Alien, so you are saying that we cannot define the style of the child tags inside the style of the parent tag!!!

Comment: @RajeshPaul no, read my answer, if you want, you can write inline style for each `span` tag

Comment: @Shomz, It will not be a problem if I can add a style tag in the segment of body. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: @RajeshPaul No problem with that: `<style>div#container span {style rules go here}</style>`

Comment: Can I add it in the middle of the `<body>`(Not in `<head>`)?
Because I can't access `<head>` section in the blog-post.

Comment: Yes, I said yes, and I mean yes.

Comment: LOL am deleting my answer.. it's waste

Answer (score 0):

One way is like this

```
div span {

/* styles */

}
```

or if you need to be more specific to the top level div put an id on it and then target that like this

```
#top_level_div span {

/* styles */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give class to parent div and then access its child node like this in css tag..

```
.fooClass span{color:red;}
```